# How to disable ssl critical extension check in Android?

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle, okhttp

I use okHTTP to send HTTPS requests to a server in my Android application. It's ok with Android version > Jelly Bean, but the following exception is thrown with Jelly Bean :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Certificate has unsupported critical extension
10-04 12:45:01.391 7570-7735/mop.orange.com.moplibapptest5 I/System.out:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
10-04 12:45:01.391 7570-7735/mop.orange.com.moplibapptest5 I/System.out:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:241)
```

It seems linked to the SSL/TLS server certificate which contains 2 extensions with the "critical" tag. I cannot change this certificate because the server is not mine.

I tried to enable / disable TLS Extensions support, but the behaviour is the same :(

```
ConnectionSpec connSpec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
     .supportsTlsExtensions(false)
     .build();

OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(connSpec))
```

Do you know how can I disable the critical extension check in okHTTP ( or in Bouncy Castle which seems to be under) please ?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [okHTTP way](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS) to [customize](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) the trusted certificates, then I wrap the TrustManager and the certificate to return an empty list of critical extensions.

Here is the TrustManager wrapping when it's a Jelly Bean class :

```
        if(trustManagers[0].getClass().toString().equals("class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl")) {
            logger.debug("Wrapping TrustManager to return no critical extension");
            return new TrustManagerNoCritical((X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0]);
        }
```

Here is the TrustManager wrap class to wrap certificates in the chain :

```
public class TrustManagerNoCritical implements X509TrustManager  {

protected X509TrustManager trustManager;

public TrustManagerNoCritical(X509TrustManager realTrustManager) {
    trustManager = realTrustManager;
}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

    List<X509Certificate> certifs = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();       

    for (X509Certificate certif : chain) {
        certifs.add(new CertificateNoCritical(certif));
    }

    X509Certificate[] newChain = new X509Certificate[certifs.size()];  
    newChain = certifs.toArray(newChain);

    trustManager.checkServerTrusted(newChain, authType);
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}

}
```

Here is a certificate class to wrap the real certificate and return no critical extension :

```
public class CertificateNoCritical extends X509Certificate {

protected X509Certificate certif;

public CertificateNoCritical(X509Certificate certificateToWrap) {
    certif = certificateToWrap;
}


@Override
public boolean hasUnsupportedCriticalExtension() {
    return certif.hasUnsupportedCriticalExtension();
}

@Override
public Set<String> getCriticalExtensionOIDs() {     
    // Return empty Set to avoid "critical extension" Exception
    return new HashSet<String>();       
}

@Override
public Set<String> getNonCriticalExtensionOIDs() {
    return certif.getNonCriticalExtensionOIDs();
}

@Override
public byte[] getExtensionValue(String oid) {
    return certif.getExtensionValue(oid);
}

@Override
public void checkValidity() throws CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
    certif.checkValidity();
}

@Override
public void checkValidity(Date date) throws CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
    certif.checkValidity(date);
}

@Override
public int getVersion() {
    return certif.getVersion();
}

@Override
public BigInteger getSerialNumber() {
    return certif.getSerialNumber();
}

@Override
public Principal getIssuerDN() {
    return certif.getIssuerDN();
}

@Override
public Principal getSubjectDN() {
    return certif.getSubjectDN();
}

@Override
public Date getNotBefore() {
    return certif.getNotBefore();
}

@Override
public Date getNotAfter() {
    return certif.getNotAfter();
}

@Override
public byte[] getTBSCertificate() throws CertificateEncodingException {
    return certif.getTBSCertificate();
}

@Override
public byte[] getSignature() {
    return certif.getSignature();
}

@Override
public String getSigAlgName() {
    return certif.getSigAlgName();
}

@Override
public String getSigAlgOID() {
    return certif.getSigAlgOID();
}

@Override
public byte[] getSigAlgParams() {
    return certif.getSigAlgParams();
}

@Override
public boolean[] getIssuerUniqueID() {
    return certif.getIssuerUniqueID();
}

@Override
public boolean[] getSubjectUniqueID() {
    return certif.getSubjectUniqueID();
}

@Override
public boolean[] getKeyUsage() {
    return certif.getKeyUsage();
}

@Override
public int getBasicConstraints() {
    return certif.getBasicConstraints();
}

@Override
public byte[] getEncoded() throws CertificateEncodingException {
    return certif.getEncoded();
}

@Override
public void verify(PublicKey key) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {
    certif.verify(key);
}

@Override
public void verify(PublicKey key, String sigProvider) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {
    certif.verify(key, sigProvider);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return certif.toString();
}

@Override
public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
    return certif.getPublicKey();
}

}
```